# Blank page with no error after i scaffolded Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

After i scaffolded identity when i run my project it gives me a blank page and the project doesn't have any errors, manually going to a page doesn't work either and when i try to view in browser a page view it gives me the same blank page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yoi3.png)

Answer (score -1):

You have not given enough information for the question to be answered. If you are using Areas then the answer can be simply that you have not defined the Area Attribute at the beginning of your controller, such as

[Area("Landing")]

If this doesn't work then post extract of your code such as the program.cs, the HomeController.cs etc.. Then someone may be able to answer your question. :)

Comment: Hey Shane, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use comments once they become available to you to ask for clarification, not answers.

Comment: you can post a comment to the OP, your answer can't be marked as a solution to the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).